# How to select a dropdown value in Selenium WebDriver using Java appium?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, testng, appium

I am new to Selenium, currently am working on selenium webdriver. I want to select a value from the drop-down. But I am not able to do it because of some error. Also, I want to inform you that in my automator viewer I have not found any id of the dropdown element hence I am using with XPath but I am not able to do please guide me. My java code is below:

```
@Test
public void print() throws Exception

{


    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);// 1 minute
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.className("android.widget.Button")));

    driver.findElementByClassName("android.widget.EditText").sendKeys("1234567890");
    driver.hideKeyboard();

    Select drpCountry = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.ImageView[@index='2']")));

    drpCountry.selectByVisibleText("+91(IN)");
    drpCountry.selectByIndex(8);

    driver.findElementByClassName("android.widget.Button").click();
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your `Select` element is one level above the thing you are capturing, try using xpath of the `View` above your `ImageView`

Comment: Hi @Moro , I have try as you said but got no any solution :(

Comment: Hey @Moro , Please guide me further what should i have to do i am stuck on it.

Comment: Have you tried simply clicking the desired `Element` from the list? I do not use appium, so despite the fact that you are capturing wrong element for a `Select` list I am not sure I can be of any help.

Comment: Yes sir, i have tried not working but its ok. and Thanks for your valuable response :)

Comment: Hi @Moro, can you please someone tag this issue to help me. I am totally stuck on it.